# how to configure rsyslog for elk-auditbeat logs are not to store in /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, rsyslog

I have installed audit-beat in my centos7, here audit-beat logs are stored in `/var/log/messages` file . Due that audit-beat logs my disk is going to full every time. How to configure `rsyslog` to not to store audit-beat logs into`/var/log/messages`file?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation at https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/filters.html ?

Comment: What have you tried? What did you expect? What didn't work? What did you debug?

Answer (score 0):

By default the `-e` flag sends output to stderr. You can remove this option from the systemd unit file(s). Should help.

```sh
sed -e '/BEAT_LOG_OPTS=-e/ s/^#*/#/' -i /lib/systemd/system/{auditbeat,metricbeat,filebeat}.service
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl restart metricbeat filebeat
```

[Found answer/clue in this thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/beats-filebeat-metricbeat-etc-log-to-syslog-with-logging-to-syslog-false/179085/4)

Note as of beats 7.7+ the configuration has changed so the above will not work.

https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/12024#issuecomment-628925105